# Blender Cycles Render Speed Optimization for animations

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, denoise, optimization

i have a couple of questions about speed optimization for Cycles Render Animations. Many of the posts that I have seen refer to older versions of Blender and are sometimes a bit contradictory. I´m using the experimental Feature Set. I would be very happy for any help!

1. Can the OptiX Denoiser also be used for animations or are there small differences/shifts between the individual frames? Some also use a denoise node. What is the difference here and when should I use what?
2. Are there any general recommendations on how I should set the subdivision field in the render settings for a full HD video? So the Dicing Rate Render, Offscreen Scale and Max Subdivisions?
   -> If I use the Simplify option, I can also limit the subdivisions. Where would be the difference to the Max Subdivisions in the Subdivision tab? Is it the same?
3. Sometimes I have quite grainy images. Now I wanted to try Multiple Importance Sampling under the World Settings, but the Sampling tab is grayed out under "Volume". I can set it to Multiple Importance Sampling, but i don´t understand why it is grayed out even if I set the sampling to manual under the surface settings. Or am I getting something wrong here?
4. Are there any other important things to do? I reduced all max light bounces and deactivated the reflective caustics.

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but here's my 2 cents: 1. Using a denoiser on an animation can be problematic as it can lead to flickering shadows, 2. With subdivisions it's worth setting your division modifier to adaptive, so that polys further from the camera are subdivided to a reduced degree, I think simplify would work the same way as reducing the max number of subdivisions, 3. I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you've written here, 4. As well as turning off caustics and lowering bounces you should: optimise your tile sizes, Enable Adaptive Sampling, Adjust clamping etc...

Comment: Note that OpenImageDenoise/OptixDenoise are much much slower than the denoise node, but much better at denoising. You must try both of them and see if you can '*get away with*' the denoise node. Also, just as @James said, denoising can lead to flickering effects

Comment: Ok thanks for your answers!
This is what I meant with the Multiple Importance Settings Option:
->https://renderpool.net/blog/stop-grainy-renders-with-blenders-multiple-importance-sampling/

Comment: But can the Denoise Node be used for animations or does this have the same problem as OptiX etc.?